# Widget on home page displays wrong time compared to same widget on inside pages

Tags: widgets, page-template, date-time

I am trying to use the timely events calendar and I have the upcoming events widget on my home page widget area. The time that displays is not the time I have selected. When I put the same widget to a different widget area that displays on the inside pages, the time is correct. Is there some kind of time setting that a widget area needs to register? Or an issue with the page template?

thanks

this is the code on the page template:

```
                    <div class="wrap">
                        <p><?php _e("This is a widgeted area which is called Homepage Bottom 3.", 'genesis'); ?></p>
                    </div><!-- end .wrap -->
                </div><!-- end .widget -->
            <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

code in functions.php:

```
genesis_register_sidebar(array( 'name'=>'Homepage Bottom 3', 'description' => 'This is a widgeted area which is called Homepage Bottom 3.', 'before_title'=>'<h4>',
'after_title'=>'</h4>'
 ));
```

I am using the All in one event calendar by timely

Comment: Please add more info on this event calendar. If you can find it also the relevant code for the widget.

Comment: added the code, as I said the same widget does display the proper time if I put it on a different widget area which appears on a different page template, so I think the problem is either the page template or the widget registration.

Answer (score -1):

Had a similar problem - from what I've read on Timely site, widget is only designed for use on external sites and causes conflicts on pages also displaying the calendar. Shame, but can't see a workaround.

Comment: "Timely" (what is this?) does not seem to be related to the OPs problem. Can you please clarify in an [edit]?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. In the future please consider using the comment function instead of the answer form, when you just want to leave a comment…